# view tabs in eclipse

Tags: eclipse

I need to view the tabs and spaces and CRLF in python source code in eclipse the same way we could see them in notepad++, Now I have to edit in notepad++ and run in eclipse. Not a neat way but eclipse does regular update of the changes of same file in other editor.

Comment: Just added an extended answer addressing the "space instead of tabs" issue

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This should be cover with the "Show invisible" option

[image: show whitespace]

From [Eclipse3.3](http://archive.eclipse.org/eclipse/downloads/drops/R-3.3-200706251500/whatsnew/eclipse-news-all.html):

> It is now possible to see the invisible whitespace characters in textual editors:
>
> This feature can either be controlled via "`General > Editors > Text Editors > Show whitespace characters`" preference, or via the tool bar button when the Editor Presentation action set is enabled.

I did not tried it with [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/), but its editor should be a "textual editor", and the option should work.

---

> when I press `TAB` it creates spaces instead of `>>` for tabs

Check the option "`General > Editors > Text Editors > Insert spaces for tabs`":
if unchecked, it will display tabs, not space.

Comment: wonderful, it does,thank you,  but when i press TAB it creates spaces instead of >> for tabs

Comment: if you have pydev you must also update pydev -> Editor "Replace tabs with spaces when typing"